# how can I change displayed text of THEME MY LOGIN register

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using Wordpress and installed plugin named TML.

I'd like to change the displayed text of this registering page without touching the features working. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVmbB.jpg)

I had checked the source code of plugin TML, and I had found this file
"theme-my-login/templates/register-form.php"

```
<?php
/*
If you would like to edit this file, copy it to your current theme's directory and edit it there.
Theme My Login will always look in your theme's directory first, before using this default template.
*/
?>
<div class="tml tml-register" id="theme-my-login<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>">
    <?php $template->the_action_template_message( 'register' ); ?>
    <?php $template->the_errors(); ?>
    <form name="registerform" id="registerform<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" action="<?php $template->the_action_url( 'register', 'login_post' ); ?>" method="post">
        <?php if ( 'email' != $theme_my_login->get_option( 'login_type' ) ) : ?>
        <p class="tml-user-login-wrap">
            <label for="user_login<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>"><?php _e( 'Username', 'theme-my-login' ); ?></label>
            <input type="text" name="user_login" id="user_login<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" class="input" value="<?php $template->the_posted_value( 'user_login' ); ?>" size="20" />
        </p>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <p class="tml-user-email-wrap">
            <label for="user_email<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>"><?php _e( 'E-mail', 'theme-my-login' ); ?></label>
            <input type="text" name="user_email" id="user_email<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" class="input" value="<?php $template->the_posted_value( 'user_email' ); ?>" size="20" />
        </p>

        <?php do_action( 'register_form' ); ?>

        <p class="tml-registration-confirmation" id="reg_passmail<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>"><?php echo apply_filters( 'tml_register_passmail_template_message', __( 'Registration confirmation will be e-mailed to you.', 'theme-my-login' ) ); ?></p>

        <p class="tml-submit-wrap">
            <input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Register', 'theme-my-login' ); ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php $template->the_redirect_url( 'register' ); ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="instance" value="<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="register" />
        </p>
    </form>
    <?php $template->the_action_links( array( 'register' => false ) ); ?>
</div>
```

Which field do I have to change for my changing display such as "Register" "Password", etc?

Answer (score 0):

You can see the field names like

The _e means "get the translation for". In thtis case for Username. And the text domain is "theme-my-login". So you can change the language file only and you are all set without editing the php files.